# Examination of the case where ImageView contains Image or not

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm working with JavaFX. I need to know how to check contains of ImageView.
E.g. If I have image inside ImageView I should recive information "true" if not "false", and the most important things - If this ImageView is empty how I can create 'if' conditions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check, if the `image` property is `null`. Now you may also want to consider a `Image` to be empty where the image could not successfully be loaded to be empty, which could be done using the following method:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(ImageView imageView) {
    Image image = imageView.getImage();
    return image == null || image.isError();
}
```

A thing you may also want to check is the `width` and `height` of the image.